# C#: "'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'" error

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, tostring

I have the following code trying to get values within a dictionary and cant seem to get it working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace DemoTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = "{\"Name\":\"Bob Smith\",\"mainTitle\":\"Title1\",\"emailList\":[\"test.e@example.com\"],\"rowCount\":\"4\",\"emailSubject\":\"Test Email\",\"items\":{\"sheets\":[[{\"ID\": \"4564342\", \"start\": \"08:00\"}]]}}";
            JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> results = jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>();
  
            List<dynamic> subList = results["items"]["sheets"].ToObject<List<dynamic>>();
            foreach (dynamic tableEntries in subList) 
            {
                var entryDict = tableEntries[0].ToObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>();
                for (int k = 0; k < entryDict.Keys.Count; k++)
                {
                    String key = entryDict.Keys.ToList()[k];
                    Console.WriteLine(key);
                }
            }
      
            }

    }
}
```

I get an error on line `String key = entryDict.Keys.ToList()[k];`

`Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'`

How can I get it running? Im pretty new to C# so also open to better ways to write my code

Comment: It might be better to just use the `JObject` you already parsed rather than all those dictionaries

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Got it. Will study the JObject a bit more. I had initially struggled getting the list of keys from it and ended up just converting to dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that entryDict.Keys has no function ToList()
The .Keys is a key collection which uses an enumerator to walk over it. You cannot acccess it like an array/list.

What you want is this:

```
foreach (var key in results.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That"s a fine solution but you didn't explain the error. And you've also asserted something which is not true. The reason it fails is because you can't call an extension method on a dynamic expression. In other words, `Keys` does indeed have a `ToList` method but it's an extension method

Answer (score -2):

create a list using a constructor

```
List<string> keyList = new List<string>(entryDict.Keys);
for (int k = 0; k < entryDict.Keys.Count; k++){
    String key = keysList[k];
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Comment: this came up with an error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.List(int)' has some invalid arguments`